# cannot get aspx files to run on server but it does run locally

Tags: asp.net

Ive made a website in Visual Studio using asp.net, my default page is default.aspx.
Im using FileZilla to add the files to the server, and Ive added everything. But when i type in the URL, it says that it cannot find default.aspx, even though its definitely there. 
also, I converted the same page to default.html, and uploaded that and it works fine. Does anyone know why I cant see my .aspx file, and how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Does your web server support ASP.NET (meaning is it IIS)?

Comment: Which version of IIS? What version of ASP.NET, and is it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the pages did not work because the server did not support aspx files, although I cannot tell you which version of it it was. I bought a Windows server and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, it was because the server I was uploading them to did not accept asp files. I bought a windows server and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have uploaded all the files and the .dll files into the server.
Make sure you have given the correct path and the iis is pointed to the virtual directory of your project.
Check the config file remove debug mode.
Check all the .dll are compiled or not.